# SQL DB2 - Embedded SELECT using MAX

Tags: sql, select, db2, max

I am having issues with a SQL statement. First of all, here are the values from my DB2 table:

```
     CLT_ID    FP_NDT      PRD_TCD  CLP_DATE_CDTTM              FP_SDT      CLP_TCD  CLP_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  100085059    2015-06-30  01       2015-11-27-20.14.28.295209  2014-07-01  01       0001-01-01
  100085059    2014-06-30  01       2015-11-27-20.14.28.284432  2013-07-01  01       0001-01-01
  100085059    2015-06-30  01       2015-11-02-20.04.39.755865  2014-07-01  01       2026-01-30
  100085059    2014-06-30  01       2015-10-15-00.00.00.001257  2013-07-01  01       2025-02-20
```

My select is supposed to return the MIN row CLP_DATE with value (0001-01-01) AND the most recent CLP_DATE_CDTTM. Here is my select that doesn't seem to work:

```
   SELECT  MIN(CLP_DATE)
     FROM  TCDECF A
     WHERE A.CLT_ID           = 100085059
       AND A.CLP_DATE        >= '2015-10-15'
       AND A.CLP_DATE_CDTTM   =
         (SELECT MAX(B.CLP_DATE_CDTTM)
               FROM  TCDECF B
               WHERE B.CLT_ID           = A.CLT_ID
                 AND B.FP_NDT           = A.FP_NDT
                 AND B.PRD_TCD          = A.PRD_TCD)
  WITH UR;
```

This code does not return anything. I'd imagine it's because of the "AND A.CLP_DATE >= '2015-10-15" line. Is there a way to say "Select anything >= than this date, but if it returns nothing ,then return 0001-01-01"?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you are expecting for the output?

Comment: I am expecting '0001-01-01' as output (the most recent row in the table according to CLP_DATE_CDTTM column, and it's the MIN value of CLP_DATE column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this works... Remove the date check from the `WHERE` clause, instead put in a conditional `MIN` in the `SELECT` list. Use `COALESCE` to return that value, or `0001-01-01` if not found (i.e `NULL` from `MIN`).

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(case when A.CLP_DATE >= '2015-10-15' then A.CLP_DATE end),date'0001-01-01')
     FROM  TCDECF A
     WHERE A.CLT_ID           = 100085059
       AND A.CLP_DATE_CDTTM   =
         (SELECT MAX(B.CLP_DATE_CDTTM)
               FROM  TCDECF B
               WHERE B.CLT_ID           = A.CLT_ID
                 AND B.FP_NDT           = A.FP_NDT
                 AND B.PRD_TCD          = A.PRD_TCD)
  WITH UR;
```